# Pointer to parent class - prevent warning message

Tags: objective-c, pointers, methods

I have a class instance that is created by an instance of a parent class. When the child class is created, it is given a pointer to the parent class, so that I can launch an instance method (*myMethod*) on the parent class from the child class.

My parent class is a UIViewController, called *myViewController*. However, XCode gives me a warning, saying that 'UIViewController may not respond to myMethod'.

The line (in the child class) that causes the error looks like this:

```
[self.parent myMethod];
```

Although this follows through and works fine, I would like to prevent the warning message. Is there something I can do to reassure XCode that there is no problem, and that 'self.parent' (which is a UIViewController) *will* respond to 'myMethod'?

Comment: Classes don't create classes.  You have an *instance* of a class that was created by an *instance* of a different class.  The distinction is important.

Comment: Thanks. Question adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could typecast it:

```
myViewController * p = (myViewController*)self.parent;
assert([p isKindOfClass:[myViewController class]]);
[p myMethod];
```

…although the design is often a smell.

Comment: No need to do that when you can declare the pointer to be the right type.

Comment: @HotLicks good point +1, although it's not wise to do so in the event `parent` is not always `myViewController` (that was my assumption).

Comment: If all the assignments are typed correctly there should be no more danger than "normal" that `parent` is the wrong type.  No casts would be required.

Comment: @HotLicks there's not enough context in the OP to determine the correct type to declare for the ivar. if the instance type varies and consequently `UIViewController` is the common base, then it should *not* be declared as `myViewController`. based on the description, it sounds likely that `parent`'s actual type is variable and that UIViewController is the common base. in that case, yes, one would wind up needing a downcast to the correct type (or `id` -- which is worse than the downcast).

Comment: Didn't sound like that to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the pointer with right class, not just UIViewController.

To avoid circular declarations, use `@class MyOwningViewController;`.  Eg, MyContainedViewController.h:

```
@class MyOwningViewController;
@interface MyContainedViewController {
    MyOwningViewController* owningViewController;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) MyOwningViewController* owningViewController;
@end;
```

But include the usual MyOwningViewController.h in MyContainedViewController.m (in addition to probably including MyContainedViewController.h in MyOwningViewController.m).

MyOwningViewController.h:

```
#import "MyContainedViewConroller.h"  // Though you could use @class here as well
@interface MyOwningViewController {
    MyContainedViewController* containedViewController;  
}
@property (strong, nonatomic)  MyContainedViewController* containedViewController;
-(void) myMethod;
@end;
```

Finally, in MyContainedViewController.m:

```
#import "MyOwningViewController.h"

...

-(void) doSomething {
   [owningViewController myMethod];
}
```